# jQuery selecting divs when there are 2.

Tags: jquery, field

Let tell you a bit about my script first. It creates a php/html render of the friend requests. As you may know, there can be 1 to many friend requests at a time. Right now my jQuery script only works for the first  so I do need some guidance to get the two to many functionality working.

Notice that my div's have a different id for each person.

FIrst here's my html

```
    <div class='fRequest'>
<h3>Pending Friend Requests:</h3><div class='friendRequest' id='0'><img src='[url]' alt='Charles Williamson'/> Charles Williamson<a id='4' class='friendConfirm' href='#' 
        style='border:1px solid #dadada; background:#fff; margin-left: 
        10px; line-height: 60px; padding: 4px 4px; color:gray; text-decoration:none;'>
        Confirm</a></br></div><div class='friendRequest' id='1'><img src='[url]' alt='Rachel Cole'/> Rachel Cole<a id='5' class='friendConfirm' href='#' 
        style='border:1px solid #dadada; background:#fff; margin-left: 
        10px; line-height: 60px; padding: 4px 4px; color:gray; text-decoration:none;'>
        Confirm</a></br></div></div>
```

Second here's my jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".friendAdded").css('display', 'none');

    var frid = $(".friendConfirm", ".friendConfirm").attr('id');

    $(".friendConfirm#"+frid).click(function(){

        $.get("JSON/addFriend.php?fid="+frid,
            function(data){
            $(".friendAdded").append(data);
            $(".friendAdded").show() })
    });
    $(".closeOwe").click(function(){
        $(".friendAdded").css('display', 'none')
        location.reload();
        });

});
```

How can I make this code work for both or many friend requests.

PS. i'm fairly new to jquery so still learning. Having trouble finding tutorials for this.

THanks for any help I can get.

Comment: I honestly don't understand what it is you're trying to do. Can you explain, step-by-step, what should happen? And what you're trying to retrieve/select?

Comment: `Having trouble finding tutorials for this.` The jQuery website has extensive documentation with code samples on how to use something for most of them. http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page, selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the `.click()` event handler to all elements with the class `friendConfirm`, and then concatenate the clicked element's `id`, referenced by `this.id`, to the `$.get()` url:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".friendAdded").css('display', 'none');

    $(".friendConfirm").click(function() {
        $.get("JSON/addFriend.php?fid="+this.id,
            function(data) {
              $(".friendAdded").append(data);
              $(".friendAdded").show() 
            }
        );
    });

    $(".closeOwe").click(function() {
        $(".friendAdded").css('display', 'none')
        location.reload();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Sweet. Wasn't sure if that existed. Good to know for future reference!

Comment: Yes, `.click()` will bind the event handler to *all* elements that match the selector, thus there's no need to bind to each `id` individually.