# Jquery HTML .load() with further jquery involvement

Tags: jquery

So I use .load to show some information from php files that output data. I want to use .load so I can refresh this data once in a while or upon a particular action. Unfortunately this affects other parts of my site. There is a button that is outputted which jquery normally intercepts. Although now I cannot select the class as it doesn't seem to be in my source code due to having used .load.

How can I get around this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you need to use jquery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to setup the click event on your button. It is not that your button does not exist, but rather it is recreated. Therefore, your initial selector will not work unless you set it up using on(). Your code would look something like this:

```
$('.fRequest').on("click", ".friendConfirm", function () {

});
```

The above code will find a static element on the page (preferably the parent of the dynamically loaded content) and will look for all elements with the class specified in the second argument. It will then attach the specified event found in the first argument to all of the found elements even if they were created after the initial pageLoad.

Just as a note, jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is for versions of jquery 1.7.1 or higher. If you are using earlier version you would want to use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: I believe that, according to the asker's (admittedly unclear) language, the button is re-rendered but doesn't respond to selectors after the update. If this reading is correct, recreating the handler isn't the issue.

Comment: I believe it is exactly the issue. If he doesn't recreate the handler, then how is it supposed to work when the content is being created dynamically? The default selectors only work when the content exists initially. You need to use on() for content that will be created later.

Comment: Oh, okay. So your saying when the data isn't recreated yet but will I should be using .on? Let me try this.

Comment: It is sort of difficult to understand what exactly is occurring on your site, but I am pretty sure jquery's on will solve your problem. Please try it out real quick and let us know.

Comment: I believe this is what my issue is. But the .on is confusing me a bit. Here was my .click code which worked.

$(".friendConfirm").click(function(){

there seems to be both button and .class but my button is my class. 
This is what I have used and not surprised I'm doing this wrong as it isn't working.

  $('.friendConfirm').on("click", ".friendConfirm",function () {

Comment: I have updated my code off of your last comment and your previous question. The first selector in jquery's on must be a static element on the page (preferably the element that will hold all of your dynamically loaded content). The first argument then tells what type of event to create then the second argument tells it what selector to apply the event to within the parent container.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you. Where on earth did you get the idea of fRequest?

Comment: Your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236841/jquery-selecting-divs-when-there-are-2

Answer (score 0):

If it's still visible on the page, jQuery should be able to interact with it - I use jQuery to alter an element that's loaded in a document that's loaded *into* a document all the time.

There are two things which I believe may be happening: either the new copy of the button that your PHP script is generating doesn't have the same ID/class/etc that your jQuery selector is relying upon, or you're selecting by ID and your update process is causing multiple buttons with the same ID to be rendered, which won't work.

Comment: Sorry for my broken english.

1. .load outputs some php code about friend requests. 
2. this code shows up on the page to the user but does NOT show in the browser's source code.
3. When the button is clicked nothing occurs.
4. the classes are identical to what it used to be. I double checked them and they are correct.

Will .on still be a solution?

Comment: "View Source" **never** includes Ajax-loaded HTML - it displays the source exactly as it appeared during the initial load. If the class is identical and you aren't re-binding the click event in a callback from your `.post` call, then I'd say that @JoshMein's answer is accurate.